# ansible select first found from dict

Tags: loops, dictionary, ansible

I have the following ansible playbook. fX is for framework version 1,2 or 3. When a file has a version >= fX it should select that framework version using a last found type method, so we don't get multiple results.

file_version >= 1.2.0 should give f2 for example, and file_version >= 2.2.0 should result in f3.

```
- name: select version
  hosts: all
  connection: local
  become: false
  vars:
    version:
      f3: '2.2.0'
      f2: '1.2.0'
      f1: '1.0.0'
  tasks:
    - name: debug loop
      debug:
        msg: "{% for F in version %}{% if file_version | version_compare(version[F],'>=') %}{{ F }} {% endif %}{% endfor %}"


ansible-playbook case.yml -i 127.0.0.1, -vv -e file_version='1.5.0'
```

Ansible should decide for me, that I should be using framework version 1.2.0 or {{ f2 }}. But of course this yields two matches

```
f1 f2
```

How can I pull out the last found version? Is there a more elegant way to do this?

Comment: "`first found from dict`" is misleading. The item doesn't have to be in the dict.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO there is no function which returns the position of an element in a list. The play below does the job in 3 steps

```
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    file_version: '1.5.0'
    version:
      f3: '2.2.0'
      f2: '1.2.0'
      f1: '1.0.0'
  tasks:
    - set_fact:
        versions: "{{ version.values() + [ file_version ] }}"
    - set_fact:
        frameworks: "{{ frameworks|default({})|combine({item: index}) }}"
      loop: "{{ versions|sort }}"
      loop_control:
        index_var: index
    - set_fact:
        framework: "f{{ frameworks[file_version] }}"
    - debug:
        var: framework
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ version[framework] }}"
```

gives

```
"framework": "f2"
"msg": "1.2.0"
```

---

With the [filter_plugins/list_methods.py](https://github.com/vbotka/ansible-plugins/blob/master/filter_plugins/list_methods/list_methods.py) the simplified play

```
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    file_version: '1.5.0'
    version:
      f3: '2.2.0'
      f2: '1.2.0'
      f1: '1.0.0'
  tasks:
    - set_fact:
        versions: "{{ version.values() + [ file_version ] }}"
    - set_fact:
       index: "{{ versions|sort|list_index(file_version) }}"
    - set_fact:
        framework: "f{{ index }}"
    - debug:
        var: framework
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ version[framework] }}"
```

gives the same results.

Answer (score 0):

Try below

```
- name: select version
  hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  become: false
  vars:
    version:
      f3: '1.2.0'
      f2: '2.2.0'
      f1: '1.0.0'
  tasks:
    - name: Set found to 0
      set_fact:
        found: '0'
    - name: Set the last value returned from the sorted dict
      set_fact:
        found: "{{ item.1 }}"
      loop: "{{ version | dictsort(False,'value') }}"
      when: "{{ file_version | version_compare(item.1,'>=') }}"
    - name: debug
      debug:
        msg: "{{ found }}"
```